# how to deal with BigINT in R

Tags: r

I have a BigInt number.If I try to store it in R

```
  R> a <- 9223372036854775807
  R> a
   [1] 9.223372e+18
```

As you can notice its loosing info of last few digits. I tried multiple other ways to solve this but no luck like increasing options(digits = 22) or changing to numeric, double, integer.

```
 > as.integer(9223372036854775807)
  [1] NA
  Warning message:
  NAs introduced by coercion to integer range 
 R> as.numeric(9223372036854775807)
  [1] 9.223372e+18
 R> as.double(9223372036854775807)
  [1] 9.223372e+18
```

Can anyone help me with this problem. I want to retain the same original value.  I also do not want to install any external package.

Comment: You may need to check `gmp` package or `bit64` i.e. `library(gmp);as.bigz(a)`

Comment: Try `options(scipen = 99)` but I think it would still loose precision.

Comment: @RonakShah: Its still losing precision   R> options(scipen = 99)
R> as.numeric(9223372036854775807)
[1] 9223372036854777856
R> as.double(9223372036854775807)
[1] 9223372036854777856

Comment: @akrun : External package unfortunately can not be installed

Comment: In that case you will lose precision with that big numbers.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `as.integer64` from `bit64`

```
library(bit64)
as.integer64(as.character(a))
#integer64
#[1] 9223372036854775807
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't install external package as mentioned in question.

Comment: @shivankagrawal  Then, probably you may have to adjust with the reduced precision,  Even if you try with `as.character`, it will reduce the accuracy i.e. `as.character(a)#
[1] "9223372036854775808"`  Check the last digit it is rounded